# host ssl and non ssl sites on same apache machine

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, iptables, https

I got apache and Ubuntu machine with static ip. Today I host sites via port 80, I want to able to host also sites with https. Is there a service I can buy that can make me ip pool or somehow solve this problem without messing with the router too much?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd need additional IPs, since the headers of the HTTP request are encrypted. You simply specify the IPs in your vhost files instead of the default *.

But this looks interesting: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/configure-apache-to-support-multiple-ssl-sites-on-a-single-ip-address/987, althought it appears to have limited support.

Comment: Search Server Fault for `SNI` or `Server Name Indication` for additional discussions on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use apache virtual hosts to host multiple port 80 sites and only one 443, You need one IP per 443 im afraid.

But if you have multiple IPs then you can use [virtual hosts.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/)